# why does from `from itertools import chain` works but not `import itertools.chain as chain`?

Tags: python, import, python-itertools

Why does the following work:

```
from itertools import chain
```

but the following does not?

```
import itertools.chain as chain
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `import foo.bar` syntax can only be used to import a module from a package, not an object in a module.  `from foo import bar` can be used to import a module from a package or an object from a module.

Comment: The tutorial chapter on [Modules](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules) and the reference docs on [`import`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) and [the import system](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/import.html#importsystem) have the full details… but this one-liner says it all.